# How Google Doodles are animated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I always wonder how these doodles are animated. Can someone give a detailed description of how these are animated. I know it's using JS to animate an image. But I would like to know how it interacts with the user clicks and timing, and it is also cross browser compatible which amazes me.

[image]

Comment: The Google engineers are really good at what they are doing ;) If you want to learn JavaScript, start with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide. You'll also have to learn about the DOM and how it works together with JavaScript and about the event system. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html is a great start for the latter.

Comment: *If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question* .... http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Why this question had been closed? A totally legitimate question.

Comment: @neoswf I agree with you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many cross-browser compatible ways in javascript to do simple things like

a.) Move an element (by changing its style position attributes)
b.) Resize/edit an element in another way (switch images, change colors, etc)
c.) Detect mouse hovers and clicks (very very common)

The smooth animation is normally given by some function that moves (or otherwise changes) an elements CSS attributes by a small amount.  Such as changing a position from (1,1) to (1,2).  This one pixel change looks very fluid.  This function is then called like a frame, many times a second (calling this function 15 times a second results in a 15 FPS (frames per second) animation).

Using Javascript events and its ability to change CSS attributes, and doing this many times a second, yields a great cross-browser animation :)